# Application demands elevated privs to run on win7 but not vista

Tags: c#, .net, installation, nsis, inno-setup

I have a simple app that I just tried the installer (Innosetup) on win7(32-bit).

After I install it the program icon on the desktop gets that shield on it that notifies the user that the app demands elevated privileges. I thought it was something wrong with the installer and made on using NSIS instead, same problem.

Does anyone know why it does that on this computer but not on xp-32, win7-64 bit or Vista 64-bit?

If I allow the app to run (Answers yes to the system prompt) it crashes with only the error " has encountered an error. Windows is looking for a solution" and then closes.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is related to the "program compatibility assistant" thinking your application is non-compatible (as you haven't specified it is) and "guessing" that it requires elevation.

Try adding a correct [Application Manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd371711(VS.85).aspx) to indicate that elevation is not required, and that Vista and Windows 7 are both supported operating systems...  Here's an example:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
  <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
    <security>
      <requestedPrivileges>
         <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="False">
         </requestedExecutionLevel>
       </requestedPrivileges>
    </security>
  </trustInfo>
  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
     <application>
        <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}"></supportedOS>
        <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}"></supportedOS>
     </application>
  </compatibility>
</assembly>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as yours on a Windows 7 machine installed via an NSIS installer: the application had the "shield" icon over the launcher and the desktop shortcut.

We resolved it adding this simple line to the NSIS script that creates our installer:

```
RequestExecutionLevel user
```

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/Chapter4.html (search for UAC)

Hope this might help resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer at least one of your questions:

You will not see the shield icon on XP because there is no concept of elevation in WinXP.  WinXP does not support the [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) that was first introduced in Vista.

However, Vista32/64 and Win7-32/64 all support UAC, so I can't imagine why there would be a difference in behavior in just Win7-32.  Did you tinker with the UAC settings in the other OSes you're testing?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not related to the installer, but the target of the shortcut (Your application?)

If windows believes that a shortcut points to a program that requires elevation, it will display the shield overlay icon. It will display it if the target has a manifest with a requestedExecutionLevel of requireAdministrator (And highestAvailable if you are admin) OR the target does not have a "Vista" manifest and windows detects that this is a patch/setup/install application or an application with compatibility problems.

I'm guessing your application does not have a manifest. If you want to remove the overlay, try adding a manifest with requestedExecutionLevel asInvoker (Not that this will turn off virtualization and other compatibility stuff for that application)